# php MQTT subscribe not work

Tags: php, mqtt, phpmqtt

I have installed MQTT broker on my windows machine from https://mosquitto.org/download/.

I am using https://github.com/bluerhinos/phpMQTT/tree/master/examples for publish and subscribe. Publish works as expected but subscribe did not work.

I did not understand why this is not work. 
MQTT broker require for connect remote MQTT server ?
I want to implement publish and subscribe method in php

**Publish:**

```
require("../phpMQTT.php");


$mqtt = new phpMQTT("host", 1883, "124464646464/32"); //Change client name to something unique

if ($mqtt->connect()) {
    echo "Connect Sucssfully";
    try
    {
        $mqtt->publish("124464646464/Test","Hello HK123! at ".date("r"),0);
        echo  "<br>publish done";
        $mqtt->close();
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e;
    }
}
```

**Subscribe:**

```
ini_set('output_buffering','on');
require("../phpMQTT.php");


$mqtt = new phpMQTT("host", 1883, "124464646464/27"); //Change client name to something unique

if(!$mqtt->connect()){
    exit(1);
}

$topics['124464646464/Test'] = array("qos"=>0, "function"=>"procmsg");
$mqtt->subscribe($topics,0);

while($mqtt->proc()){

}


$mqtt->close();

function procmsg($topic,$msg){
        echo "Msg Recieved: ".date("r")."\nTopic:{$topic}\n$msg\n";
}
```

**Error:**
wrong subscribe header

Get error form host error log

**Edit:**

I have run subscribe script using command line and it's always print 
"eof receive going to reconnect for good measure\n" means always get true from `feof` function

**code:**

```
if(feof($this->socket)){
                if($this->debug) echo "eof receive going to reconnect for good measure\n";
                fclose($this->socket);
                $this->connect_auto(false);
                if(count($this->topics))
                    $this->subscribe($this->topics);    
            }
```

I have tested my publish page using chrome extension means subscribe using chrome extension and it's working fine means something in wrong in read socket .

Comment: show some code, Also how did you know that publish is working fine ?

Comment: Your code only shows the publish step, please include your subscribe code as that is the bit you said wasn't working

Comment: @hardillb: added subscribe code

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @German: no, I did not find anything.

Comment: I was able to reproduce problem. There seems to be a bug in this mqtt client.

Comment: Have you find any solution for fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Update the `phpMQTT.php` file:

```
private $socket=8080;           /* holds the socket */
```